# pagination data from the dynamoDB using node.js SDK V3

Tags: node.js, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Im using dynamoDB databse as aws has been update with sdk v3 for JS
i want to update my pagination api
with page=1 request i got the data with LastEvaluatedKey = { MCNo: { N: '456' } } and im passing this to
api/test?page=2&lastEvaluatedKey={ MCNo: { N: '456' } }

having error in this api is
Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

```
 const page = parseInt(req.query.page, 10) || 1;
  const pageSize = 10;

  const startKey = page === 1 ? undefined : { pageKey: req.query.lastEvaluatedKey };
    console.log(page, startKey,"test one")
  const scanParams = {
    TableName: 'carrier',
    ExclusiveStartKey: startKey,
    Limit: pageSize,
  };

  const scanCommand = new ScanCommand(scanParams);

  const result = await dbV3.send(scanCommand);

  const items = result.Items;

  const response = {
    data: items,
    nextPage: result.LastEvaluatedKey ? `${req.originalUrl}?page=${page + 1}&lastEvaluatedKey=${result.LastEvaluatedKey}` : null,
  };

  res.json(response);

} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error:', error);
  res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
> }
```

Answer (score 0):

> having error in this api is Requested resource not found

[ResourceNotFoundException](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html#Programming.Errors.MessagesAndCodes.http400) is telling you that for your account/region which you have configured it is not able to find a table named `carrier`.

- Double check the role which you use is for the correct account.
- Double check that you configure the correct region
- Double check the table exists and the name matches (case sensitive)